# CasperJS form AJAX results do not appear

Tags: ajax, webforms, casperjs

I am trying to scrape some website results after a form submit.

Using Chrome Developer Tools console, I am able to fill out the form and submit. On the Network tab, there are two POSTs, and then results appear on the page.

I’m trying to mimic this process unsuccessfully with CasperJS.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
clientScripts: ["./jquery.min.js"],
verbose: true,
logLevel: 'debug',
pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36',
    webSecurityEnabled: false,
}
});

casper.start('https://ptabtrials.uspto.gov', function() {});

casper.thenOpen('https://ptabtrials.uspto.gov/prweb/PRWebLDAP2?UserIdentifier=searchuser', function() {
        this.evaluate(function(search){
            return jQuery('input#SearchTrialNumber').attr({'value': search});
        }, 'ipr');

        this.evaluate(function(){
            return jQuery('div.pzbtn-mid:contains("Search")').click();  
        });
});
```

This next part is where it breaks. It seems like the page never refreshes with new content, and the process hangs on `casper.waitUntilVisible`:

```
casper.waitUntilVisible("#PEGA_GRID_CONTENT", function(){
        var results = this.evaluate(function(){
            return jQuery("#PEGA_GRID_CONTENT tr.cellCont").size();
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

The terminal responds with `[warning] [phantom] Casper.waitFor() timeout`. Using waitFor() seems correct because the form is refreshed with AJAX.

I modified jQuery to avoid `$` namespace conflict with the existing code, to use `jQuery` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no click handler on the `div.pzbtn-mid:contains("Search")`. You should use:

```
this.evaluate(function(){
    return jQuery('button:contains("Search")').click();  
});
```

instead of

```
this.evaluate(function(){
    return jQuery('div.pzbtn-mid:contains("Search")').click();  
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'm having one more problem. The JS popup doesn't seem to be detected https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d3f489d9deea2318e797 This works in console, but still doesn't in CasperJS. Is there a good way to approach debugging?

Comment: If the selector click doesn't work you could try to use the casper `mouse` module either with the XPath selector `mouse.click(x("//a[contains(text(),'IPR')]"))` or creating the mousedown and mouseup events yourself in the page context on the correct mouse position. There is something fishy with the click handling on the site.